# REST client model in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing a Cake application that pulls data from the database as well as from a third-party REST API. I'd like to implement the REST API properly using models for the various REST collections I'm trying to access (inheriting from a single behaviour), but I can't get my model working without a corresponding database table. My original plan was to create `class Software extends Cake\ORM\Entity` and `class SoftwaresTable extends Cake\ORM\Table`, then use the `before*` hooks to override the various calls and reroute them to the API rather than the database.

However, I've added `die()` to `beforeMarshal`, `beforeRules`, `beforeFind`, `beforeSave`, and `beforeDelete`, and calling `$this->Softwares->all()` from the controller still fails with the message

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'inventory.softwares' doesn't exist

Is my approach wrong? Something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks @ndm; I missed that post. Everything I was able to find about REST and Cake was either a) about CakePHP 2, or b) about making a REST client rather than a REST server.

Comment: Why do you want to make a REst client using the Table API? What is the end goal for you?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo The goal is to abstract the data access layer, same reason we use database models.

Comment: here is a proper guide addressing your issue - http://geekoat.blogspot.in/2016/05/how-to-use-cakephp-3-as-middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your models to be backed by a database table don't use `Cake\ORM\Table`. Instead make your own base model class which implements `Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface`. Then make your models extend this base class.

It's not a trivial task, but better than the alternative you are trying of hacking around the `Table` class' callbacks to prevent them from connecting to database.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for an easier solution, but I suppose it's better to do it right. I'll see about implementing the base class as a plugin and open-sourcing it for the sake of the next person with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for CakePHP 3, it seems the models are coupled to a database data source.

In CakePHP 2.x, you could define your own data sources, so could have easily swapped it to be provided by an external API as opposed to a database, but I can’t see that functionality on first glance (someone who’s worked with CakePHP 3 more than me may be able to say otherwise).

Saying that, there is an [`EntityTrait`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php). You may be better off creating your own classes to represent each entity, and then adding that trait to your classes. For example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityTrait;

class Software {

    use EntityTrait;

}
```

Comment: So far I don't anticipate any issues with the entities; it's the ORM (SoftwaresTable) that isn't cooperating as far as I can tell. But I haven't gotten the table class to spawn any entities, so that may become a problem down the road. Like you, I've had to do quite a bit of rooting around in the Cake source looking for an answer; it's great that there's so much in-code documentation, but I'm not impressed by the gaps left by the online documentation that forced both of us to get our hands dirty...